Google OAuth 2.0 Policy Compliance Error during token exchange
I’m working on integrating Google OAuth 2.0 into my application for Gmail API, and I’m facing an issue that I can’t seem to resolve.

Note: I’m not showing my actual domain—so when I say mydomain, it represents my real domain.

This is the URL I used to obtain the authorization code. I have URL-encoded the redirect URI (and the client_id here isn't real, I just want to show the format):
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=7037-5863r8r.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.mydomain.com%2Fapi%2Foauth%2Fcallback&scope=profile%20email&response_type=code&access_type=offline

After navigating to this URL, I can successfully sign in, and I receive the authorization code at the callback endpoint.
But when I try to exchange the authorization code for an access token using the following cURL command:
curl -v -X POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token ^
-d "code=<AUTH_CODE>" ^
-d "client_id=<CLIENT_ID>" ^
-d "client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>" ^
-d "redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.mydomain.com%2Fapi%2Foauth%2Fcallback" ^
-d "grant_type=authorization_code"

I receive the error:
{
 "error": "invalid_request",
 "error_description": "\nYou can’t sign in to this app because it doesn’t comply with Google’s        OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.\n\nYou can let the app developer know that this app doesn’t comply with one or more Google validation rules.\n"

The error isn't formatted well either:

}
Could this error be related to some other compliance check from Google that I’m not aware of? Do I need to submit the app for verification, even though I’m in testing mode and only using test users?

My app is in testing mode, and it’s set to external.
I’ve added my email (and other users) to the list of test users.
My scopes are restricted, but as a test, I removed them and added only a non-sensitive scope, and still had the issue.
The OAuth consent screen is fully configured with the correct details, including the authorized domain and redirect URI.
DNS settings and redirection from api.mydomain.com to my backend work (an Azure function app).
In the Google Cloud Console, I set up the OAuth consent screen with mydomain.com as the authorized domain and https://api.mydomain.com/api/oauth/callback as the redirect URI.



Perhaps --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

I added that and it didn't make a difference.

The authorization code must be URL-encoded (too). Consider replacing -d with --data-urlencode and then you use the raw value(s).

I tried that too, still doesn't work :(

I tried this and it works for me so I'm unable to repro your issue
